# Is performing fetch for NSFetchedResultsController on a background thread a good idea?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

When a user runs the app, he first has to login. If the login is successful, a function called setUpSaving is triggered. In setUpSaving, as I wrote in the commented part of the code, (   "some firebase stuff happens, grabs all the messages, and for each message, one by one, it goes through createMessageWithText and inserts the message into core data, eventually saving it. "

So, my problem is here. Let's assume that a user has 20 000 messages associated with someone he is messaging. When he goes to the ChatLogController, all the messages must be present for the user. The way I did that is by using NSFetchedResultsController perform fetch to load all the messages that were saved in the login controller. My problem with that is that all of this is on the main queue, and sometimes, that has frozen the UI for quite some time. My code for chatLogController is below (not all of it, just the fetchedResultsController part and the collectionView), I was wondering how I could perform fetch on a background queue, yet still update the collectionView on the main queue.

```
  func setUpSaving() {

///////some firebase stuff happens, grabs all the messages, and for each message, one by one, it goes through createMessageWithText and inserts the message into core data, 
  somewhere along the line context.save() gets triggered saving the message. 


}

private func createMessageWithText(text: String, friend: Friend, context: NSManagedObjectContext, date: NSDate, isSender: Bool = false, sentStatus: String, fromID: String) -> Mesages {

    let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Mesages", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Mesages
    message.user = friend
    message.text = text
    message.timestamp = date
    message.isSender = isSender
    message.fromID = fromID

    message.status = sentStatus



    return message

}
```

}

```
lazy var fetchedResultsControler: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
    fetchRequest.includesPendingChanges = false
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", self.friend!.id!)
    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NavigationItems()
    revealStatus()

    do {
        try fetchedResultsControler.performFetch()


    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }

 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) ->

    Int {
        if let count = fetchedResultsControler.sections?[0].numberOfObjects {
            return count
        }
        return 0
}

   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not fetch an FRC that will drive the UI on a background thread.

Your issue is the idea behind loading 20,000 items after login. No-one can or will view that number of messages on a mobile device. You might want to get 20 after login, and the total count, but that's it.

When the user goes to view messages you should load pages, of perhaps 20 to 100 messages, on demand. In this way you don't use resources the user hasn't asked you to use or take any processing time to do it.

Search should also be done by a server.

Comment: Hi Wain, thanks for the reply. Although what do you mean by "Search should be done by a server" . I didnt mention any search features. Although if its something I'm missing I would appreciate the input!

Comment: i'm guessing that you might say search is the reason for having 20k items local on the device...

Comment: oh, well then, everything is grabbed from firebase and saved to core data, not sure what the issue with that would be.

Comment: there is no good reason to have 20k items locally on a mobile device other than that app is to be used offline as a primary use case.